# Error while using variables and definitions which are included using a include(file) in php

Tags: php, include, undefined

i know this question has been asked lot of times, i did go through most of them but none of the solutions seems to be working for me.
i have to include mainly three files, which are all included in includes/ connect_db, functions and config.
In config i have used define(dir_somefile,'includes/filename') and also i have used some functions from includes/function.php.
but it always give me error saying undefined variables or address. i am attaching codes of mainpage, config,connect and functions if anyone wants them.

mainpage:

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php");
    include(DIR_DB_CONNECT_SITE);
    include(DIR_DB_FUNCTION_SITE);
    $sqlabout="select aboutus_id,title,content from ".TABLE_ABOUTUS." order by aboutus_id";
    $resultabout=exec_query($sqlabout,"Get About Details");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

config.php:

```
$runon=1;
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$DBHOST="localhost";
    $DBNAME="brainsan_mjmp";
    $DBUSER="root";
    $DBPASSWORD="";
    define('DIRPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mjmp/property_images");
    define('THUMB_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mjmp/property_images/thumbnail");
     //define('DIRPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mjmp/member_images");

// define the directories details used in Front section
  define('DIR_DB_CONNECT_SITE', 'includes/connect_db.php');       // for db connection
  define('DIR_DB_FUNCTION_SITE', 'includes/function.php');        // for reusable functions
  define('DIR_DB_CLASSES_SITE', 'includes/classes.php');          // (file/image) upload class
  define('DIR_DB_SECURE_SITE', 'includes/secure.php');            // secure login file
  define('DIR_DB_MEMBER_SECURE_SITE', 'includes/member-secure.php');            // secure login file
  define('DIR_MEMBER_IMAGES_SITE','member_images/');           // uploaded member images
  define('DIR_PROPERTY_IMAGES_SITE','property_images/');       // uploaded property images
  define('DIR_THUMB_IMAGES_SITE','property_images/thumbnail/');                      // uploaded images home dir path
  define('DIR_ADS_SITE','advt/');                               // uploaded advertisement images
```

connect_db.php:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASSWORD) or die("<b>DataBase Connection Error!</b>");
$connection = mysql_select_db($DBNAME,$link) or die("<b> DataBase Select Error!</b>".mysql_error());
?>
```

function.php:

```
<?
//function to execute a query
function exec_query($sql,$title)
{
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error in <b>$title</b> <br>".$sql."<br>". mysql_error();
        exit();
    }
}
```

these files are much bigger but i have only added the part that i thought was relevant.
Please tell me if more is needed.
files:
mainpage.php
includes/connect_db.php,function.php,confg.php

errors:

Use of undefined constant DIR_DB_CONNECT_SITE - assumed 'DIR_DB_CONNECT_SITE' 

Warning: include(DIR_DB_CONNECT_SITE): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

Fatal error: Call to undefined function exec_query()

Comment: your server is not configured to get variable in `include` funcion

Comment: So how do i configure it to include it? can you guide me? thanks.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: i am using WAMP 2.4. BTW this code works fine when run online.

Comment: could you add an example of error message?

Comment: click on wamp icon and go to php setting and `allow_url_include`

Comment: i have added the errors at the end.

Comment: StaticVariable, nothing changed after allow_url_include. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be confusing in PHP, since few really understand how include_path works.

One solution I've found works for a lot of people is to fix up their include paths so that PHP searches the base directory of their project.

**config/config.php**

```
/* fix up include paths */
$include_path = ini_get('include_path');
$include_path = sprintf("%s%s%s", $include_path, PATH_SEPARATOR, realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));
ini_set('include_path', $include_path);
$include_path = ini_get('include_path');
define('APPROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));
```

**index.php**

```
require_once("config/config.php"); // once this is called, you can use relative paths
require_once("config/database.php"); // like this
require_once(APPROOT . "/config/memcached.php"); // or use APPROOT like this
```

**deeply/nested/index.php**

```
require_once("../../config/config.php"); // once this is called, you can use relative paths
require_once("config/database.php"); // like this
require_once(APPROOT . "/config/memcached.php"); // or use APPROOT like this
```

Comment: I am quite new to PHP, am i supposed to add this code to the mainpage?? thanks.

Comment: Also i think config.php is being included succesfully as i dont get any error for it,but when i use variables/definitions  in config i get it as undefined.

Comment: If the variables in config.php are undefined, you probably aren't including it properly.  Maybe create a sample project just to play with include_path until you understand it a little better.

Comment: In my example, you use the relative path to config.php, which adds your application root to the include_path.  After that, you can use paths relative to your application root for all future includes.  Makes it kind of nice and tidy and easy to understand.  When in doubt, use getcwd() to find the directory in which your script is executing.